# how to control the mobile robot (two wheels) moving?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_robot&cat=build_robot
In step 10. Under the Force/Velocity tab, increase the force/velocity applied to each joint. The robot should move around.
Question: How to set the different velocity for each wheel using C++ plugin. This means I can control the mobile robot to move using C++ code plugin, not set the velocity in the GUI of Gazebo by manually.

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17076/how-to-control-the-mobile-robot-(two-wheels)-moving?/) by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

this tutorial on [Setting Velocity on Joints and Links](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=set_velocity&cat=) should help

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-08-22**:
It is working, Thank you very much!